# Populating second DropDownList using option selected in first

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

The task is pretty basic: I have to create 2 dropdownlists, first for car brand and second for its model, for example "Opel" -> "Astra". The second dropdownlist should be populated depending on the option selected in the 1st one. 
I want to provide ViewModel to my View, not ViewBag.

I searched for various similar topics, borrowed some code, still could not make it work.

**Model:**

```
public class CarBrand
{
    public byte Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Car Brand Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class CarModel
{
    public byte Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Car Model Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte CarBrandId { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class CarsViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<CarBrand> BrandList { get; set; }
    public CarBrand CarBrands { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CarModel> ModelList { get; set; }
    public CarModel CarModels { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var carBrands = GetCarBrands();
        var carModels = GetCarModelsOpel();
        var viewModel = new CarsViewModel
        {
            BrandList = carBrands,
            ModelList = carModels
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    public JsonResult FetchModels(int brandId)
    {
        var carBrands = GetCarBrands();
        IEnumerable<CarModel> models = new List<CarModel>();
        switch (brandId)
        {
            case 1:
                models = GetCarModelsOpel();
                break;
            case 2:
                models = GetCarModelsVolksWagen();
                break;
            case 3:
                models = GetCarModelsBmw();
                break;
        }
        var viewModel = new CarsViewModel()
        {
            BrandList = carBrands,
            ModelList = models
        };
        return Json(viewModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**View**

```
    @model CU.ViewModels.CarsViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddCar", "Cars"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CarBrands.Name)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CarBrands.Id,
            new SelectList(Model.BrandList, "Id", "Name"), "Select Car Brand",
            new {id = "brand_dll", @class = "form-control"})
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CarModels.Name)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CarModels.Id,
            new SelectList(Model.ModelList, "Id", "Name"), "Select Car Model",
            new {id = "model_dll", @class = "form-control"})
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
}
@section scripts
{
    <script>
        var url = '@Url.Action("FetchModels", "Cars")';
        var models = $('#models_dll');
        $("#brand_dll").change(function() {
            var id = $(this).val();
            $.getJSON(url,
                { brandId: id },
                function(response) {
                    models.empty();
                    $.each(response,
                        function(index, item) {
                            models.append($('</option>').text(item));
                        });
                });
        });
    </script>

}
```

I'm not getting any errors or exceptions, but the 2nd dropdownlist keeps information that it received from Index Action Method no matter of what is selected in 1st one.

I'm still just learning. Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: I think issue is in adding options, `models.append($('<option />', { value :item, text:item});`

Comment: Well I think it would over killing loading all the data for all the brands, I suggest you using Ajax for requests under the hood when a user makes a selections

Comment: Are you even hitting the `FetchModels()` method. That is returning a `CarsViewModel` so `$.each(response,,,` would not do anything - you returning a single object, not an array (and why in the world are you returning `CarsViewModel` anyway - all you want is list of the `Name`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you, i changed it so that now it returns list of Names, but it is still not working.

Comment: What is not working? Use you browser tools to debug your script.

Comment: Well to be honest I'm studying mvc, and i got task that forces me to use jquery, which i have not learned yet. I used to deal with tasks involving ajax, with ajax.helpers, now looks like its not enough anymore. Still, thanks for constructive feedback and your time. Seems like it's a good time to learn some jquery basics.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I found and fixed my problem, could you please explain to me why is this working this way. I changed </option> to <option>, removed section scripts and moved my jquery references in Shared>_Layout above RenderBody(). Changing any of this 3 back makes it stop working like before. Why does section scripts harm at all?

Comment: `$('</option>')` makes not difference. For the others I assume you had duplicate scripts or scripts in the wrong order (you have not shown the relevant code so just a guess).But the code you have shown would never work if your still using `return Json(viewModel, .. );` in the controller anyway

Comment: @StephenMuecke I fixed problem with views and scripts. The problem was that, I was writing `@section scripts` in partial view. Still changing `$('<option>')` into `$('</option>')` clears second dropdownlist initial content but never populates it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you have is due to you only appending a closing option tag instead of using .

Another way to do this, I found it easier is to return all your options as a string from your controller action and append it to the selects html, see below:

```
 //POST: Quote/SubGroupByGroup
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SubGroupByGroup(int _EquipmentGroupID)
    {
        string Options = "";
        DAL.GetEquipmentSubGroupsDropdown(_EquipmentGroupID).ForEach(delegate (EquipmentSubGroup SG)
        {
            Options += "<option value='" + SG.EquipmentGroupID + "'>" + SG.Code + "</option>";
        });

        return Content(Options);

    }
```

and the JQuery method

```
 $('#Equipment_EquipmentGroupID').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SubGroupByGroup", "Quote")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { _EquipmentGroupID: $(this).val() },
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#Equipment_EquipmentSubGroupID').html(data);
            }
        });
    })
```

I hope this gives you some guidance

Comment: thank you! Could you please also try to answer my question to Stephan Muecke in comments before your answer?